# Don't have Bisect Tool icon (Blender 2.90.1)

Tags: blender

When in Editing Mode on an object, I only have the icon for the Knife Tool on the left. There is no Bisect Tool, even when hovering over Knife Tool.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's left-clicking and dragging to the right. **Who dreamt this up**? In the rest of the software world you have to either hover over the button, or right-click, to get a submenu.